# Discussion of *real-life* systems design/usability

Tags: discussion

Are questions about the design and usability of systems/processes/interfaces which are *not* computer-related appropriate and on-topic for the UX StackExchange?

Does there exist an online community, whether it be part of the StackExchange community or not, where such questions would be more obviously well-suited? (I'm thinking of some sort of "systems design" or "process engineering" or "human factors" forum, if something like that existed?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User experience encompasses anything where people deal with tools regardless those tools being physical or digital. There's even a dedicated tag [physical](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/physical/) for such questions.

However, not all process design falls under the scope of UX. Business or manufacturing processes that deal only with value creation or science would be such offtopic discussions.

Comment: > "Not all process design falls under the scope of UX" Agreed. And the question I have in mind that I'm looking for a place to post probably doesn't. Do you have any suggestions of other online communities that might be better suited?

Comment: @thecommexokid: What kind of process is it?

Answer (score 1):

I would love to see more questions about UX that aren't related to a digital product.  My background is also more in systems design, and it's one of the areas that needs a lot more UX.

So if you have a good UX question on any systems that is focused on the "user", then I would generally say that it's on topic and would support it.